# ASP.NET User Accounts from existing DB schema

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, membership-provider

First off: ASP.NET Web Application project with SQL Server 2008

I have inherited an ancient DB with a table called Security that stores user accounts. The columns are:

ID, name, user_name, password, and access_level.

access_level holds an integer value of 1 to 3 specifying access to certain parts of the web app. These range from 1 = user, 2 = power user, 3 = admin. I will need some users to view some info, hide it for others, and make it viewable+editable for others according to this access level.

I am familiar with older ASP.NET so I am new to the provider model. From what I have read so far I can:

1) create a custom MembershipProvider and RoleProvider and use those

2) create my own login system using hidden text fields to persist data

What is the best way to implement this? I started writing a custom MembershipProvider but it seems overkill for such a simple schema. There has to be a simpler method to implement this. Any suggestions or clarifications are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do **not need to restrict pages** based on the authorized roles, you can simply use

```
// After custom validation
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);
```

However, if you want to **restrict pages** based on the authorized role (in web.config), I'll suggest to implement Custom MembershipProvider and RoleProvider.

You just need to override the following methods.

**MembershipProvider**

```
public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)

public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)
```

**RoleProvider**

```
public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)

public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom control for Login or Registration module. It may easy to understand and debugging. Also when a member is going to sign in you can check for access_level and give rights for access.